# Different number of matches with xpath and string()

Tags: xpath, vim, xmllint

I use xmllint as an external command in VIM editor. When I ran the command below on a buffer containing well-formed xml

```
%!xmllint --xpath '//a/@href' --encode UTF-8 -
```

it returned the number of matches that I expected. But as I wanted only the values of `href's` I ran the other command that made use of `string()`:

```
%!xmllint --xpath 'string(//a/@href)' --encode UTF-8 -
```

but I was very surprised to see only the value of the first matched `href`. Don't I understand something in XPath or is it a bug?

I can attach the source XML (ca 450 lines) if needed but I think it should be clear from the description that the culprit is somewhere else.

Comment: First duplicate link explains the behavior you're seeing.  (xmllint supports XPath 1.0.)  Second duplicate link provides some apropos xmllint tips.

Comment: @kjhughes Thank you for providing links to the similar questions. So the problem is in the old XPath version that xmllint uses. If xmllint used XPath 2.0 the expression '//a/@href/string()' would do that I expect. Anyway, to workaround the issue I use the first expression '//a/@href' and pipe the result to 'sed' where I only extract the value of href.